# Using Hazel Cast to synchronize instances in a cluster

Tags: spring, hibernate, hazelcast

In my work place, we have a java system (tomcat,spring,hibernate,soap+rest web services). Some of the web services require the server to save state. For example, while performing some long service, the client cannot call the same service again, as long as it is not finished.
Currently, we don't support clustering, in order to avoid running the above mentioned long service, we use locks or synchronize blocks. In order to support clustering we consider using Hazel Cast (share the locks across the instances), will it work? 
Is this the right solution?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, maybe as the most typical use case; you can use distributed locks or other distribured data structures to share state between different servers (or jvms).